# jQuery efficiently load multiple divs with one .get() call

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

```
$.get('text.php', {}, function(data) {
    var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
    var $jeremy= $response.find('#jeremy')
    var $kyle = $response.find('#kyle');
    $('#right').append($jeremy).append($kyle);
},'html');
```

Would the above be the most efficient and DRY method of calling in multiple div's with one ajax call?

Comment: What are your trying to do here: `var $response = $('<div />').html(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More efficient and less DRY but less readable too:

```
$.get('text.php', {}, function(data) {
    $('#right').append( $('<div />').html(data).find('#jeremy, #kyle') );
},'html');
```